# Both Dark Barracks Under Upgrade

Tags: clash-of-clans

The current barrack system has a single queue for all troops be it elixir troops or dark elixir troops. I know how the training time is calculated and all the other stuff. I would like to know what would happen if I decide to upgrade both dark barracks at the same time. Will I be able to train dark troops as there is a single queue for all troops or I won't be able to train any dark troops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not be able to train dark troops while your dark barracks are upgrading.  You can train normal troops from the normal barracks.

From the coc wiki:  barracks will not function while under upgrade.
http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Barracks

Comment: I feel it is out-dated as http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/clashofclans/images/9/95/Maintenance.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/650?cb=20140201051224